# Using dot notation in a JSON property name (e.g. "payment.token")

Tags: c#, object, json.net

I am working on a script that has to make an API request. Currently, the object to send to the API looks like this:

```
var request = new
{
    amount = new
    {
        currency = amount.Currency,
        value = amount.Amount
    },
    additionalData = new AdditionalData
    {
        ApplePayToken = paymentToken
    }
};
```

The issue is, the API expects the following format to receive the additionalData property:

```
"additionalData":{
    "payment.token": "some-token"
}
```

I'm using the following code to try to reformat the object above:

```
internal partial class AdditionalData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="additionalData.payment.token")]
    public string ApplePayToken { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get this to work? Right now, the code doesn't seem to change anything about the request object. It generates it like this:

```
"additionalData":{
    "ApplePayToken": "some-token"
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `Dictionary<string, object>` for `AdditionalData` (assuming there aren't any repeated keys)?

Comment: I'm very new to C#, so I don't really understand what you mean. Can you give me an example of how you would implement that? There are no repeated keys in this case.

Comment: I think the following way is the right way to specify: `[JsonProperty("payment.token")]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the rest of your request appears to be an anonymous object, instead of making a class only for `AdditionalData`, you could just use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var request = new
{
    amount = new
    {
        currency = amount.Currency,
        value = amount.Amount
    },
    additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "payment.token", "some-token" }
    }
};
```

Since you said you're new to C#, note that I'm using the object initializer pattern for the dictionary, which is equivalent to pre-building the dictionary and assigning it to the anyonymous object's `additionalData`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> addtData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
addtData.Add("payment.token", "some-token");

var request = new
{
    amount = new
    {
        currency = amount.Currency,
        value = amount.Amount
    },
    additionalData = addtData
};
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZNLBA93528)

Alternatively, you could make all of the classes you need in C#:

```
class Request
{
    public Amount amount { get; set; }
    public AdditionalData additionalData { get; set; }
}

class Amount
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public decimal value { get; set; }
}

class AdditionalData
{
    [JsonProperty("payment.token")]
    public string applePayToken { get; set; }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JQIFQ53714)